# How do I change the width of the "Sign In with Apple" button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nslayoutconstraint

I am embedding a "Sign In with Apple" Button in SwiftUI using a UIViewRepresentable struct to display the button.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AuthenticationServices

final class AppleIDButton: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = UIView

    var appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AppleIDButton>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.addSubview(appleButton)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AppleIDButton>) {
        appleButton.cornerRadius = 8
    }
}
```

...//Here is the code in my SwiftUI file

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: screenWidth, height: 1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color("lineGray"))

                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.375)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }

                    VStack {

                        HStack {
                            self.appleIDButton
                                .frame(width: screenWidth - 24, height: 48)
                                .padding(.leading, 24)
                        }
                            .padding(.bottom, 16)


                        Text("Or")
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("gray"))
                            .padding(.top, -16)
                        NavigationLink(destination: SignUpView()) {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Sign Up with email")
                                    .font(.system(size: 17))
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .padding([.top, .bottom], 12)
                        }
                            .background(colors.primaryThemeColor, cornerRadius: 8)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)
                            .padding(.bottom)

                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Already have an account?")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("gray"))

                            NavigationLink(destination: SignInView()) {
                                Text("Sign In")
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .foregroundColor(colors.primaryThemeColor)
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    }
                        .padding(.top, 24)
                }
```

My code is currently producing a button that is less than half the width of the screen and is touching the leading edge.

When it shows up in the SwiftUI view, How do I change the width of the button to match the right view constraints?

Comment: One thought is to do it in `UIKit`. All you've really done is set a `cornerRadius` to it. I'm guessing if you added a `backgroundColor` of orange (my favorite garish debugging color to `AppleIDButton` you'll see (1) that the `appleButton` is only part of the entire view and (2) that `appleIDButton` in `SwiftUI` is the full width of the screen or `hStack`. So first thing I would do is - via constraints or something else - make it be the **full** `UIKit` view. Once that's done, the rest of your work is in `SwiftUI`.

Comment: Consider adding more code to show us the context in which that button is placed. If you cannot include the whole view, at least the container it is in and its siblings (i.e.,Text("Or"),  the "Sign Up with email" button). We cannot debug layout problems in isolation. Layout, in itself, depends on the interaction between components. So we need to see those components and how you assembled them.

Comment: Thanks. I added more code. I did put an orange background color behind the button and the only orange that shows up is in the corners of the button.

Comment: Not the SwiftUI way but you can change width with a autolayout solution like below;

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AppleIDButton>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        // autolayout solution
        appleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        appleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth * 0.6).isActive = true
        appleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(appleButton)
        return view
    }

Comment: Thanks Berk! That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

You can modify the default constraints and set new ones.
By default the width needs to be greater than 130.

- Objective - C

```
ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton *appleButton = [[ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton alloc] init];
[appleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSignInWithAppleIDButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Disable default width constraints
[appleButton.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof NSLayoutConstraint * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (obj.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth) {
        obj.active = NO;
    }
}];

// Set new ones
//[appleButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:150].active = YES;
[appleButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = YES;
[appleButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:40].active = YES;
```

- Swift

```
let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogInWithAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)

// Disable default width constraints
appleButton.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
    if (constraint.firstAttribute == .width) {
            constraint.isActive = false
    }
}

// Set new ones
//appleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
appleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: dont forget the .isActive = true in the swift version, should be `appleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot when I translated to Swift.

Answer (score 9):

It's a usual process what we tend to miss is

```
appleSignInButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

When apple button is Programatically added Auto resizing is enabled and your constraint changes would not respond.

Happy coding